# Better script to restart mysql on Ubuntu 8.04

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu, daemon, init.d

When I say `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart` on Ubuntu 8.04.2 sometimes there remains a `mysql_safe` process eating 99% of cpu. Making the machine practically unusable.

Is there a better way to restart mysql? I thought about writing a script:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
sleep 10
sudo killall mysql_safe
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start
```

But this would be a evil workaround. (And the script is just a quick shot)

I googled and found that `mysql_safe` is a wrapper script which starts `mysqld`, and makes sure it gets restarted if it should die. So there should be a better way to restart the thing.

I googled that this is a common problem in this ubuntu version. Is Debian / Ubuntu doing it wrong at this point? The `/etc/init.d` script looks quite sophisticated, and it deals with `mysql_safe` also, but my skills are not good enough to understand it fully. But this would be the best place to improve. This is a paste of the version on my machine (which is untouched):

```
#!/bin/bash
#
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          mysql
# Required-Start:    $remote_fs $syslog mysql-ndb
# Required-Stop:     $remote_fs $syslog mysql-ndb
# Should-Start:      $network $named $time
# Should-Stop:       $network $named $time
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Start and stop the mysql database server daemon
# Description:       Controls the main MySQL database server daemon "mysqld"
#                    and its wrapper script "mysqld_safe".
### END INIT INFO
#
set -e
set -u
${DEBIAN_SCRIPT_DEBUG:+ set -v -x}

test -x /usr/sbin/mysqld || exit 0

. /lib/lsb/init-functions

SELF=$(cd $(dirname $0); pwd -P)/$(basename $0)
CONF=/etc/mysql/my.cnf
MYADMIN="/usr/bin/mysqladmin --defaults-file=/etc/mysql/debian.cnf"

# priority can be overriden and "-s" adds output to stderr
ERR_LOGGER="logger -p daemon.err -t /etc/init.d/mysql -i"

# Safeguard (relative paths, core dumps..)
cd /
umask 077

# mysqladmin likes to read /root/.my.cnf. This is usually not what I want
# as many admins e.g. only store a password without a username there and
# so break my scripts.
export HOME=/etc/mysql/

## Fetch a particular option from mysql's invocation.
#
# Usage: void mysqld_get_param option
mysqld_get_param() {
        /usr/sbin/mysqld --print-defaults \
                | tr " " "\n" \
                | grep -- "--$1" \
                | tail -n 1 \
                | cut -d= -f2
}

## Do some sanity checks before even trying to start mysqld.
sanity_checks() {
  # check for config file
  if [ ! -r /etc/mysql/my.cnf ]; then
    log_warning_msg "$0: WARNING: /etc/mysql/my.cnf cannot be read. See README.Debian.gz"
    echo                "WARNING: /etc/mysql/my.cnf cannot be read. See README.Debian.gz" | $ERR_LOGGER
  fi

  # check for diskspace shortage
  datadir=`mysqld_get_param datadir`
  if LC_ALL=C BLOCKSIZE= df --portability $datadir/. | tail -n 1 | awk '{ exit ($4>4096) }'; then
    log_failure_msg "$0: ERROR: The partition with $datadir is too full!"
    echo                "ERROR: The partition with $datadir is too full!" | $ERR_LOGGER
    exit 1
  fi
}

## Checks if there is a server running and if so if it is accessible.
#
# check_alive insists on a pingable server
# check_dead also fails if there is a lost mysqld in the process list
#
# Usage: boolean mysqld_status [check_alive|check_dead] [warn|nowarn]
mysqld_status () {
    ping_output=`$MYADMIN ping 2>&1`; ping_alive=$(( ! $? ))

    ps_alive=0
    pidfile=`mysqld_get_param pid-file`
    if [ -f "$pidfile" ] && ps `cat $pidfile` >/dev/null 2>&1; then ps_alive=1; fi

    if [ "$1" = "check_alive"  -a  $ping_alive = 1 ] ||
       [ "$1" = "check_dead"   -a  $ping_alive = 0  -a  $ps_alive = 0 ]; then
        return 0 # EXIT_SUCCESS
    else
        if [ "$2" = "warn" ]; then
            echo -e "$ps_alive processes alive and '$MYADMIN ping' resulted in\n$ping_output\n" | $ERR_LOGGER -p daemon.debug
        fi
        return 1 # EXIT_FAILURE
    fi
}

#
# main()
#

case "${1:-''}" in
  'start')
        sanity_checks;
        # Start daemon
        log_daemon_msg "Starting MySQL database server" "mysqld"
        if mysqld_status check_alive nowarn; then
           log_progress_msg "already running"
           log_end_msg 0
        else
            /usr/bin/mysqld_safe > /dev/null 2>&1 &
            # 6s was reported in #352070 to be too few when using ndbcluster
            for i in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14; do
                sleep 1
                if mysqld_status check_alive nowarn ; then break; fi
                log_progress_msg "."
            done
            if mysqld_status check_alive warn; then
                log_end_msg 0
                # Now start mysqlcheck or whatever the admin wants.
                output=$(/etc/mysql/debian-start)
                [ -n "$output" ] && log_action_msg "$output"
            else
                log_end_msg 1
                log_failure_msg "Please take a look at the syslog"
            fi
        fi

        # Some warnings
        if $MYADMIN variables | egrep -q have_bdb.*YES; then
            echo "BerkeleyDB is obsolete, see /usr/share/doc/mysql-server-5.0/README.Debian.gz" | $ERR_LOGGER -p daemon.info
        fi
        if [ -f /etc/mysql/debian-log-rotate.conf ]; then
            echo "/etc/mysql/debian-log-rotate.conf is obsolete, see /usr/share/doc/mysql-server-5.0/NEWS.Debian.gz" | $ERR_L
        fi
        ;;

  'stop')
        # * As a passwordless mysqladmin (e.g. via ~/.my.cnf) must be possible
        # at least for cron, we can rely on it here, too. (although we have
        # to specify it explicit as e.g. sudo environments points to the normal
        # users home and not /root)
        log_daemon_msg "Stopping MySQL database server" "mysqld"
        if ! mysqld_status check_dead nowarn; then
          set +e
          shutdown_out=`$MYADMIN shutdown 2>&1`; r=$?
          set -e
          if [ "$r" -ne 0 ]; then
            log_end_msg 1
            [ "$VERBOSE" != "no" ] && log_failure_msg "Error: $shutdown_out"
            log_daemon_msg "Killing MySQL database server by signal" "mysqld"
            killall -15 mysqld
            server_down=
            for i in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10; do
              sleep 1
              if mysqld_status check_dead nowarn; then server_down=1; break; fi
            done
          if test -z "$server_down"; then killall -9 mysqld; fi
          fi
        fi

        if ! mysqld_status check_dead warn; then
          log_end_msg 1
          log_failure_msg "Please stop MySQL manually and read /usr/share/doc/mysql-server-5.0/README.Debian.gz!"
          exit -1
        else
          log_end_msg 0
        fi
        ;;

  'restart')
        set +e; $SELF stop; set -e
        $SELF start
        ;;

  'reload'|'force-reload')
        log_daemon_msg "Reloading MySQL database server" "mysqld"
        $MYADMIN reload
        log_end_msg 0
        ;;

  'status')
        if mysqld_status check_alive nowarn; then
          log_action_msg "$($MYADMIN version)"
        else
          log_action_msg "MySQL is stopped."
          exit 3
        fi
        ;;

  *)
        echo "Usage: $SELF start|stop|restart|reload|force-reload|status"
        exit 1
        ;;
esac
```

I found many hints, but I would like this resolved to a certain degree of reliability for production servers.

**Edit**: It seems to be exactly [this unsolved bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mysql-dfsg-5.0/+bug/105457).

Maybe it is [this bug from the MySQL site](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=36550).

[This](http://forum.slicehost.com/comments.php?DiscussionID=1000) seems related or identical.

Some people talk of a race condition with 2 instances of `mysql_safe`. Others suggest commentiong out the sanity check in the startup script.

Answer (score 2):

I would try to figure out what is causing the CPU issue, rather than investigate how to re-write the startup script.  The startup script is fairly standard and should work well in a production environment.

Comment: It was a clean install on a fresh system, no config changes, and it is also on some bug lists. I added links to the question above. I don't know how to repeat the behaviour but it was clearly there.

Comment: I supose the loop is caused by an infinite loop in the mysql_safe shell script. It was suggested by some people to insert a sleep command into the script but this alone would not remove the bug